# Change/Degrade Docker API version

Tags: docker

Need some serious help, I have installed docker on ubuntu18.04, and also tested through command 'docker run hello-world', it ran successfully.  Now when I run 'docker compose up -d', it says

> **'Error :Couldn't connect to docker daemon.You may need to create docker-machine start default'.**

Also when checked error through docker --verbose it says

> **'Error:Bad Request : Client API version is too new 1.36 -Maximum supported API version is 1.35'.**

that's the case then how can I upgrade the API-version in for docker? My docker version is 17.12.

Answer (score 0):

Plz check if you are running the correct command, it is:

> docker-compose up -d

you are missing a "-"